# Problem with Hub-Site Navigation Settings (Stuck in Classic Mode?)

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, modern-experience, global-navigation, top-navigation

We are currently overhauling our SharePoint intranet at my company and have now made the intranet start page into a hub-site.

However, since that old start page was created many moons ago, it seems that the Navigation Settings are also inherited from that ancient time (see screenshot below).

Does anyone of you know how I can change the settings into Modern SharePoint, where you simply build the navigation on the page instead of going to this separate cryptic settings section?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Normally when using Modern experience, Library, List, etc. are used in modern experience, and List settings and Site settings are used in classic experience.

This is a default behavior.
[image]